# Krita Animation, How to render only key frames?

Tags: krita

**Krita Animation**

How to render key frames from one or more selected layers or layers inside a group.

Is there way to script this?

Comment: What have you tried and what specifically are you having trouble with. Have you checked the [Animation section in the Krita Documentation](https://docs.krita.org/Animation)?

Comment: Yes i have gone through it before. The render **Image Sequence** render all the frames from First frame to Last frame specified.

What i am looking for is only key frames with no inbetweens.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only way to export things in Krita is to specify a range...from frame 0 to frame 30 for example.

I haven't looked that much into the Python API, but I don't thin it is possible right now to check the frame data to see if it has content. I am sure that is possible, but that just isn't in the Python API right now

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is really what your trying to do but I made some keyframes created a second layer on the layer with the keyframes I copied the frames I wanted to clipboard and then went to the second layer and pasted from clipboard. you can also click and drag the keyframes to reorder them. I would try copying the frames you want to hide to another layer and hide the layer. then on the other layer arrange the leftover frames the way you want. sorry if I am bad at making any sense of this.